# Foreach no razor com model de relação de Muitos para Muitos no Entity Framework Core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Eu tenho uma tabela de `funcionário` e uma tabela de `projeto` relacionadas com muitos para muitos como mostra o diagrama abaixo:
[image: Diagrama demostrando as tabelas]

Na controladora `FuncionariosController` no método `Detalhes` eu quero listar a lista de projetos que eles está envolvido. No método populo a model e envio para a view como abaixo:

```
    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var model = new Funcionario();
        using( var DBContext = new DadosProjetosContext() ) {
            model = DBContext.Funcionario
            .Include(a => a.FuncionarioProjeto)
            .Where(a => a.FuncionarioId == id )
            .Single()
            ;}

        return View(model);
    }
```

Na view estou fazendo o seguinte `foreach` para listar os projetos:

```
    <div class="container">
        @foreach (var FP in Model.FuncionarioProjeto) {
            <a asp-controller="Projetos" asp-action="Detalhes" asp-route-id="@FP.Projeto.ProjetoId" class="btn-bracketed">
                @FP.Projeto.Nome
            </a>
            <br>
        }
    </div>
```

Porém estou recebendo o erro `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` na hora de chamar a página. Como solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A exceção `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` geralmente se deve à tentativa de acessar um objeto vazio usando razor.

Neste caso a variável `@FP.Projeto` está vazia, isso porque na controladora, no momento de fazer a query usando linq não está trazendo os projetos relacionados, apenas a coleção de `FuncionarioProjeto` devido o `.Include(a => a.FuncionarioProjeto)` só incluir `FuncionarioProjeto` e não `FuncionarioProjeto.Projeto`.

Para incluir os `FuncionarioProjeto.Projeto` além de `FuncionarioProjeto` é usado a método `.ThenInclude()`, resultando no seguinte:

```
    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var model = new Funcionario();
        using( var DBContext = new DadosProjetosContext() ) {
            model = DBContext.Funcionario
            .Include(a => a.FuncionarioProjeto)
            .ThenInclude(b => b.Projeto)
            .Where(a => a.FuncionarioId == id )
            .Single()
            ;}

        return View(model);
    }
```

Fonte: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html